# Google Sheets running very slow, can I host it on Google Cloud instance like Compute?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have a Google Sheet that 15+ people access throughout the workday for 10 hours a day. All of these users edit the document, make comments, etc.  It has 8+ tabs with the main tab having 50+ columns and over 200+ rows of data (roughly 10,000 cells of info).

On top of this, we have a script that automatically moves rows to a new tab depending on a dropdown choice, plus 15+ conditional formatting rules for various columns. We were under the impression Sheets could handle this volume but it is PAINFULLY slow!  In many cases it locks up the browser and people need to restart.

So my question is, can we move this Sheet to a Google Cloud Compute account and have better success there?  I am thinking our users would go to a subdomain that points to the instance's IP address and then access the sheet but would the Sharing rules still apply?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you cannot run Google Sheets yourself because Google Sheets is a hosted service (SaaS) where the code to run it is not provided to end users.

You can use Google Cloud Platform to run applications that are built with software you have written yourself, open-source software, or commercial software for which you have obtained a proper license.

Also, Google Cloud Platform runs on the same infrastructure that powers other Google services, including Google Sheets, so it's already running on the same hardware, networking, etc.

To address your issue with Google Sheets, first try going through [this troubleshooting flow](https://support.google.com/docs/troubleshooter/2853025) to see if it will help. If none of the suggestions solve your problem, at the end, it will provide links to forums and support contacts who can assist you further.

Hope this helps.